# Android Layout Weight Exactly Twice Of Others

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I would like to simply divide a Linear Layout to 3 piece. I did something as in the code below. If I change the weight of second inner layout anything else than 2, it works. But if I change it to 2(two), the second inner layout doesn't appear in the design ?

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/Main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/HomePageIcon"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingHorizontal="33dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use height as 0dp for all 3 child linear layouts

Comment: Set height to every inner layout as 0 Dp and remove gravity from the second inner layout

Comment: you can try by adding weight sum as 1 and divide all the three sub layout with layout weight as .3, .3, .3. , if there is a better solution please let me know too

Comment: Yes there is as others mentioned set the inner layouts weights to 0dp.

Comment: your second linear layout has weight 2 make it 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like below height set to `0dp` when orientation is vertical.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/background_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/HomePageIcon"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingHorizontal="33dp"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: One more question, is it better to use Constraint  Layouts in such cases ?

Comment: For dividing in `Weight` `LinearLayout` is better solution .

Comment: When I develop an interface, the locations of buttons and padding between them changes dramatically when I change the screen size, even I use dp values. To prevent this can I use Constraint Layout, or do you have any other advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Constraint Layout and forget the Linear and Relative layout.

Comment: What is the advantage of using Constraint Layout instead of Linear or Relative layout.

Comment: @Tugberk Constraint layout helps to have flat view hierarchy which intern improves performance while layout is rendered. It has hell lot of advantages. Please check out this link https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/HomePageIcon"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingHorizontal="33dp"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `layout_weight` that means your inner layouts will take the height as much as is available to it. So, in that case there is no need of using `layout_height = "wrap_content"` just change it to `android:layout_height="0dp"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="4">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/HomePageIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:paddingHorizontal="33dp"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think I have some problems about the weight term. Thank you for reply. It works.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using weight than use `0dp` to `android:layout_width` or `android:layout_height` which you want for affect using weight. And its good to use `android:weightSum` in parent layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/HomePageIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="33dp"></LinearLayout>
```